# Start up script not executing recursively, how to fix?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm on archlinux using bspwm and this is my .config/bspwm/bspwmrc file:

```
#!/bin/sh

pgrep -x sxhkd > /dev/null || sxhkd &

bspc monitor HDMI-1 -d I II III IV V VI VII
bspc monitor HDMI-2 -d VIII IX X

bspc config border_width         2
bspc config window_gap           12
#bspc config top_padding 0
#bspc config bottom_padding 0

bspc config split_ratio          0.5
bspc config border_width         2
bspc config borderless_monocle   true
bspc config gapless_monocle      true
bspc config focus_follows_pointer true
#bspc config auto_alternate true #
#bspc config auto_cancel true #
bspc config focused_border_color \#7a5014
bspc config active_border_color \#4d4b48
bspc config normal_border_color \#4d4b48
bspc config presel_border_color "#9a875f"
bspc config urgent_border_color "#504339"
bspc config focused_locked_border_color "#8c644c"
#bspc config normal_frame_opacity 0.0
#bspc config focused_frame_opacity 0.1

bspc rule -a Gimp desktop='^8' state=floating follow=on
bspc rule -a mplayer2 state=floating
bspc rule -a Kupfer.py focus=on
bspc rule -a Screenkey manage=off
bspc rule -a discord desktop='^10' state=floating rectangle=1230x724+1943+148
#bspc rule -a Pcmanfm state=floating
bspc rule -a mpv state=fullscreen
bspc rule -a feh state=floating rectangle=1600x900+100+100
bspc rule -a vlc state=floating
bspc rule -a heroic state=floating
bspc rule -a Lutris state=floating
bspc rule -a Steam state=floating
bspc rule -a zsnes state=fullscreen
bspc rule -a lxappearance desktop='^8'
bspc rule -a Lxappearance desktop='^8'
#bspc rule -a terminator -o desktop='^10' state=floating rectangle 100x100+0+0 sticky=on

~/.fehbg &
/usr/bin/numlockx on &
xinput --set-prop 13 286 -1 &
~/.config/polybar/launch.sh &
picom &
bash ~/.config/extra_config_files/bspwm_extra_exec &
```

on the last line I tell it to execute this bspwm_extra_exec file:

```
sleep 0.5
alacritty --hold -e mocp|bspc rule -a Alacritty -o desktop='^3' state=floating rectangle=759x505+1145+559 &
sleep 0.5
alacritty --hold -e cava|bspc rule -a Alacritty -o desktop='^3' state=floating rectangle=759x184+1145+359 &
sleep 0.5
alacritty --hold -e peaclock|bspc rule -a Alacritty -o desktop='^3' state=floating rectangle=759x305+1145+38 &
sleep 0.5
alacritty|bspc rule -a Alacritty -o desktop='^3' state=floating rectangle=1117x200+12+864 &
sleep 0.5
alacritty|bspc rule -a Alacritty -o desktop='^3' state=floating rectangle=1117x810+12+38 &
sleep 1
alttab &
```

so far so good, but when alacritty is openning it does not open correctly, sometimes it reads the 4th line first, then the 6th, then the 2nd and so on...

I can't get it to execute recursively, step by step. I have to re-execute for it to work properly.

Comment: Do you realize that he pipeline to `bscp rule` is not being executed in the alacritty terminal emulator? You need quotes around the `-e` argument to pass it all to `alacritty`.

Comment: Didn't know that but the `bspc rule` was working without the quotes.

Comment: Recursion might add "duplcate" slice of memory usage for every instance.  If you are doing things recursively, you should look at whether you are hitting a defined limit for allowed count of processes, or allowed total memory consumption.  Beyond that, you might not be passing an expected variable or the expected environment.